# What is the best practices to retrieve roles from database then displays item depending roles in AngularJS/Knockout/Ember

Tags: angularjs, ember.js, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Suppose I have a table Roles in database, administrator can add/delete role, assign permission for each role. What is the best practices to retrieve roles from DB then display items depending on each role. I saw a lot of samples, but they always use fixed roles in JS
We can do it easily in server side, but I want to know a best way to implement it in AngularJS/Knockout/Ember
Thank you so much

Comment: I done one such kind using `binding handlers` in ko on html controls which will hide/show , disable/enable based on access level . i suggest to refer bindingHandlers concept which will be bit tricky in ko docs . cheers

Comment: Can you suggest a specific link please. As far as I understand, it's still a kind of using fixed roles in HTML. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in the past while using Knockout is a 3-step approach:

1. Write an object to the page (while rendering) which details the user's privileges. For example

   var privileges = { CanView: true, CanEdit: true, CanAssignRoles: false };
2. Write a general-purpose function which takes a parameter stating the required privilege, and which will retrieve the above object and determine whether the user's privilege is at the required level.
3. In your view-model, add functions such as

   self.CanAssignRoles = function() { return determineAccess('CanAssignRoles'); };

   Then reference `CanAssignRoles` in the HTML binding.

   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="visible: CanAssignRoles" />

As for how you get that `privileges` object onto the page, that depends upon your server-side technology (.NET, PHP, *etc*.).

Comment: It looks great, but I think it will be better if we attach permissions into each object in the case business rules are complex. For example, I have new contact and I want to share with my colleagues, but I don't want they can delete/update that contact.